# How to query component with a multi-value component link field inside

Tags: query, brokerquery

I need to query for components that all have the same component linked inside a multi-value component link field.

I can query simple string fields without problem using CustomMetaKeyCriteria/CustomMetaValueCriteria but I cant find a solution trying to ask for a common component.

This is my field definition for the main component

[image: Field definition]

And this is a component with the multi-value field filled.

[image: Component example]

The closest result I got is if I only ask for components with the multi-value field filled with anything.

```
{
"SortingClass": "Sorting",
"Sorting": "{\"sortParameters\":[]}",
"CriteriaClass": "AndCriteria",
"Criteria": "{\"criteriaName\":\"AND\",\"criteriaChildren\":[{\"CLASSNAME\":\"PublicationCriteria\",\"INSTANCE\":{\"publicationId\":5,\"criteriaName\":\"PublicationCriteria\",\"criteriaChildren\":[],\"isOperator\":false,\"operator\":\"EQUAL\"}},{\"CLASSNAME\":\"ItemSchemaCriteria\",\"INSTANCE\":{\"publicationId\":5,\"schemaId\":514,\"criteriaName\":\"ItemSchemaCriteria\",\"criteriaChildren\":[],\"isOperator\":false,\"operator\":\"EQUAL\"}},{\"CLASSNAME\":\"CustomMetaKeyCriteria\",\"INSTANCE\":{\"keyName\":\"poi\",\"criteriaName\":\"CustomMetaKeyCriteria\",\"criteriaChildren\":[],\"isOperator\":false,\"operator\":\"EQUAL\"}}],\"isOperator\":true,\"operator\":\"EQUAL\"}"
```

}

I would like to ask, for example, for all components that have the component link "POI - Citadel"

Comment: Hi, welcome to Tridion Stack exchange, David! Are these links in the linking Component's metadata? If so, are you able to use the `CustomMetaValueCriteria` filter to check on values?

Comment: Hi Alvin. I tried but CustomMetaValueCriteria only seems to work with simple data types. How would you build a criteria to ask for a component? And yes the linking is inside component's metadata.

Comment: Hmm, it's be a while since I've worked with the criteria filters, but I'd first start with pulling the item's (custom) metadata in Content Delivery. I'm guessing the multi-value field will come back in some format (array, strings, or numbers perhaps). And then that'll tell you what to look for via CustomMetaValueCriteria.

Comment: Oh and what's the use case for this content on the website or application? The "Where Used" functionality and API is a bit more apparent on the Content Manager side, whereas Content Delivery is geared towards links and resolving. Is there a chance you could change the links so you have the _linked_ Component instead _linking_ to the Components you're looking for?

Comment: Well, in my data model I have hotels and POIs (points of interest) The idea is to relate hotels and nearby POIs so I can ask the system things like: which hotels are near this POI?

What do you mean with ask to Content Delivery?

Comment: OK - with your use case (linking POIs to a given hotel) I wonder if you can't just publish the POI IDs with your hotel page or component? Then use these to fetch them on the delivery side. If you want to dynamically add or remove POIs then perhaps using a keyword might be a better option. (Tag POIs with keywords that map to the hotel(s) they "belong" to)

Comment: Thanks @NunoLinhares. I'll give it a try. I'll talk to the content team to see if its possible to change the data model.